# printf() - prints wrong order. Works when printed separately

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to print some text in common log format.

```
printf("%s - - [%s] %s %d %zu\n", ip, _time, row, statuscode, size);
```

The problem is that the order gets all mixed up. The output is:

```
200 1511 - - [20/Sep/2017:13:07:32 +0200] GET / HTTP/1.1
```

I **think** (`1511`) is the `ip` getting printed. Don't know why.

When I print them like this:

```
printf("1. %s\n", ip);
printf("2. %s\n", _time);
printf("3. %s\n", row);
printf("4. %d\n", statuscode);
printf("5. %zu\n", size);
```

It works like expected:

```
1. 127.0.0.1
2. 20/Sep/2017:13:11:24 +0200
3. GET / HTTP/1.1
4. 200
5. 151
```

It seems the problem starts when i add `statuscode` for some reason. I have no clue why. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the function where I use prinft():

```
static void handlelogging(char* method, struct sockaddr_storage client_addr, size_t size, char* row, int statuscode) {

char* ip;
char _time[80];
struct tm *info;
time_t rawtime;

time(&rawtime);
info = localtime(&rawtime);
strftime(_time, 80,"%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z", info)
ip = getip(client_addr);

//Print goes here, see above.
}
```

As someone said it could be a problem with the ip variable:

```
static char* getip(struct sockaddr_storage client_addr) {
    char ipstr[20];
    struct sockaddr_in *s;


    s = (struct sockaddr_in *) &client_addr;

    /**
     * Converts network address (s) in the IPV_4 family into a string.
     */
    return strdup(inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr));
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data types match? Otherwise you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: In your example "ip" variable points to some other place, where the string "200 151..." is  stored, which is surprisingly similar to not-fully-parsed-yet status code and length. Double-check where it is pointing and its null-termination.

Comment: [The `od` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html) (originally "octal dump", IIRC) is a useful tool here, if you're running on a POSIX or POSIX-like system.  Instead of `myprogram`, run something like `myprogram | od -c` to see every character printed, including control characters like a `\r` carriage return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the problem comes from `row` which contains a `\r` character.

Just modify it with `strchr(...)`

```
/* replace all '\r' by 'R' in row */
char *p = strchr(row, '\r');
while(p)
{ 
    *p = 'R';
    p = strchr(row, '\r');
}
```

Comment: When I use that the program doesn't print anything. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: I think you are indeed correct, however I would change '\r' for '\n' I think that was the intended use?